# Find the surface area on $z= y^ 2 + x ^2$ below both $z=1$ and $z= x/ 2 +y$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Hey I graphed these functions but what I don't get is how to get my limits of integration for this problem
I know the integral has to follow the form

$$\iint \sqrt{1+(2x)^2+(2y)^2}\,dx dy$$

(Note: I know that these are indefinite integral symbols but as yet I haven't been able to find the limits and please forgive that I don't know the mathjax for the square root.)

I get how to do the rest of the question once I find the limits but I am absolutely puzzled how you get them here 
Thanks to whoever answers this!

Comment: Hello @Dogelover, welcome to MSE. For this time, I typeset your question as good as possible. [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) you can find a tutorial on MathJax.

Comment: You want $z\le\min(1,x/2+y)$, so you should look at the portion of the unit disk $x^2+y^2\le 1$ where $x/2+y\le 1$.

Comment: I think your formula for the area is wrong.

Comment: Got it @Andrei thanks!

Comment: The integrand is still wrong. Do you know how to do surface area of a parametrized surface? It might be easier to do the integral in polar coordinates, although this problem is a mess, regardless.

Comment: I know how to do it in polar the r^2 =x^2+y^2 but I need the limits of integration

Comment: When you graph those functions, start with $z=x^2+y^2$. Then show $z=1$. What's the intersection between these two surfaces? Now ignore the $z=1$ plane, and draw the $z=x/2+y$ plane instead. What's the intersection? The last step is the intersection of the two planes. What's the intersection? Now choose a random point $(x,y)$. Can you find if the corresponding $z$ is below the given planes? You will encounter three types of points: above at least one of the planes, below the planes when $z=1$ is lower, and below the planes when $z=1$ is higher.